# use custom column list in pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as below

```
ID,Region,year,output
1,ANZ,1978,1
1,ANZ,2019,1
1,ANZ,2021,1
1,ASEAN,2021,1
1,ASEAN,2021,2
1,ASEAN,2020,3
2,UK,2021,8
2,UK,2021,1
2,UK,2021,0
```

I would like to do the below

a) create 4 year columns `year_2019,year_2020,year_2021 and year_2022`.

b) put the count of records for each `ID` under the respective `year` columns

I tried the below

```
pd.crosstab(
      index=tf['ID'], columns=tf['year'],
      values=tf['year'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

But the problem is it convert all year values as columns in output dataframe.

My real dataframe has 4 million rows and has 50 unique year values.(from 1970 to 2022)

But I want the count of year values only for 2019,2020,2021 and 2022.

I expect my output to be like as below

```
ID,year_2019,year_2020,year_2021,year_2022
1,1,1,3,0
2,0,0,3,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (pd
 .crosstab(df['ID'], df['year'])
 .reindex(range(2019, 2022+1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
 .add_prefix('year_')
 .reset_index()
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
   ID  year_2019  year_2020  year_2021  year_2022
0   1          1          1          3          0
1   2          0          0          3          0
```

Comment: I don't get your question, `range` is the python builtin, it takes the min and max value (max being excluded, thus the +1)

Comment: you could also use an arbitrary list: `.reindex([2019, 2020, 2021, 2022], ...)`

Comment: For some reason, all 4 year, it returns 0 as count in my real data. is it index issue? Any idea on what could be the reason? Am unable to figure out why

Comment: is it because my `year` value is `object` type? and index is numeric? Some of my year values can be `NA` and it is expected

Comment: or you could use `map(str, range(2019, 2022+1))`