# Pandas get nunique using crosstab and custom columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as below

```
ID,design_id,year,output
1,21345,1978,1
1,3456,2019,1
1,5678,2021,1
1,7890,2021,1
1,5678,2021,2
1,1357,2020,3
2,9876,2021,8
2,9865,2021,1
2,9678,2021,0
```

I would like to do the below

a) create 4 year columns `year_2019,year_2020,year_2021 and year_2022`.

b) put the count of unique `design_id` for each `ID` under the respective `year` columns

I tried the below 2 approaches with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72643835/use-custom-column-list-in-pandas-crosstab)

```
pd.crosstab(
      index=tf['ID'], columns=tf['year'],
      values=tf['design_id'], aggfunc='nunique').fillna(0)

-------------------------------------

out = (pd
 .crosstab(df['ID'], df['year'])
 .reindex(range(2019, 2022+1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
 .add_prefix('year_')
 .reset_index()
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

My real dataframe has 4 million rows and has 50 unique year values.(from 1970 to 2022)

But I want the count of unique design id (and not the count of records) for each `ID` under each `year` columns `2019,2020,2021 and 2022`.

I expect my output to be like as below

```
ID,year_2019,year_2020,year_2021,year_2022
1,1,1,2,0
2,0,0,3,0
```

Comment: the first cross tab solution in your question, did return the same result as you expect. What is missing?  btw. your dataframe data don't have 2022, but your expected result has it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
y = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]


print(
    df[df.year.isin(y)]
    .pivot_table(
        index="ID",
        columns="year",
        values="design_id",
        aggfunc="nunique",
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .reindex(y, axis="columns", fill_value=0)
    .add_prefix("year_")
)
```

Prints:

```
year  year_2019  year_2020  year_2021  year_2022
ID                                              
1             1          1          2          0
2             0          0          3          0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(columns=['output'], inplace=True)
df_grouped = df.groupby(['ID', 'year']).agg('nunique')
final_df = df_grouped.unstack(['year']).fillna(0)
```

gives `final_df` as

```
     design_id               
year      1978 2019 2020 2021
ID                           
1          1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
2          0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
```

Does this satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

based on the solution you indicated. you can change columns names as follows

```
df2=pd.crosstab(
      index=df['ID'], columns=df['year'],
      values=df['design_id'], aggfunc='nunique').fillna(0)
df2.columns = ["year_"+str(col) for col in np.arange(2019,2023)]
df2.reset_index()
```

```
    ID  year_2019   year_2020   year_2021   year_2022
0   1      1.0         1.0         1.0        2.0
1   2      0.0         0.0         0.0        3.0
```

OR

```
df2=pd.crosstab(
      index=df['ID'], columns=df['year'],
      values=df['design_id'], aggfunc='nunique').fillna(0).add_prefix('year_')
df2
```

```
year    year_1978   year_2019   year_2020   year_2021
ID              
1         1.0         1.0         1.0         2.0
2         0.0         0.0         0.0         3.0
```

Comment: [add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) might be helpful to handle the `year_` part instead of hard coding a range. e.g. `pd.crosstab(...).fillna(0).add_prefix('year_')...` Using `add_prefix` would also prevent the current issue which is that the first column header was `1978` and was overwritten with `year_2019` due to the hard coded range.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker for the suggestion. Appreciate it. I'm not certain if the question asks to change the year to a different series or just like to add year as prefix. I added the solution with your suggestion as an alternate solution.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the result you ask for in your question:

```py
y = df[['ID','year','design_id']].drop_duplicates().groupby(['ID','year']).count().unstack(
    fill_value=0).droplevel(0, axis=1).reindex(
    fill_value=0, columns=[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]).add_prefix('year_').reset_index()
y.columns.name = None
```

Output:

```
   ID  year_2019  year_2020  year_2021  year_2022
0   1          1          1          2          0
1   2          0          0          3          0
```

Explanation:

- Using `drop_duplicates()` on the `ID, year` key together with `design_id` then `count()` on `groupby()` of the key gets the desired counts
- Using `unstack()` creates columns using the years with data for one or more `ID` values
- Using `droplevel()` eliminates the unneeded `design_id` level of the column multiindex (which resulted from `unstack()`), after which using `reindex()` with the desired years `2019, 2020, 2021, 2022` followed by `add_prefix()` creates the desired column labels `year_2019, year_2020, year_2021, year_2022` with the corresponding data (zero-filled where missing, such as for 2022)
- Using `reset_index()` moves `ID` from the index to a new column.